# Find Specific Text Within HTML Tag in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've tried a million different ways to parse out the zestimate, but have yet to be successful.

here's the html tag with the zestimate info:

```
<span>
  <span tabindex="0" role="button">
    <span class="sc-bGbJRg iiEDXU ds-dashed-underline">
      Zestimate
    <sup>®</sup>
    </span>
  </span>
  :&nbsp;
  <span>$331,425</span>
</span>
```

Honestly I thought this would get me close, but I get an empty list:

```
link = 'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1404-Clearwing-Cir-Georgetown-TX-78626/121721750_zpid/'
searched_word = '<span class="sc-bGbJRg iiEDXU ds-dashed-underline">Zestimate<sup>®</sup></span>'
test_page = requests.Session().get(link, headers=req_headers)
test_soup = BeautifulSoup(test_page.content, 'lxml')
results = test_soup('span',string='searched_word')
print(results)[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get correct HTML from the site, add `User-Agent` header to request.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1404-Clearwing-Cir-Georgetown-TX-78626/121721750_zpid/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

home_value = soup.select_one('h4:contains("Home value")').find_next('p').get_text(strip=True)
print(home_value)
```

Prints:

```
$331,425
```

Comment: I keep getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'"

Comment: @max Try to do `print(soup)` and verify that you don't get captcha page

Comment: @max Sounds like you may be getting captcha. Modify @AndrejKesely code so that `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}` and see if that works for you.

Comment: @AndrejKesely ah dang, didn't take the time to read the results of that soup variable. it was a captcha page. I added a different header and it worked:          
req_headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
}

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks so much. you have no idea how much time i spent trying to figure out both of those issues. i got nonetype all the time and didn't realize why. at this point i'm over this whole thing. But anyways, thanks again.

Comment: @AndrejKesely and eNc one more ? I'm actually trying to loop this code over a dataframe column where the column contains links to different zillow pages. Getting the same damn "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'" 
code is here:
for link in df['links']:
    test_soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link, headers=req_headers).content, 'html.parser')
    results = test_soup.select_one('h4:contains("Home value")').find_next('p').get_text(strip=True)
    print(results)[0] 

---- also, test_soup gets the html, not the captcha. made sure of that. Any ideas?